# How to determine the custom class from an Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am using ASP.NET MVC with C# and Entity Framework. I have three model classes in my code-first model.

```
public class Project
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public guid ProjectTypeId{ get; set; }
    public string projectType{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationDate{ get; set; }
    //more properties here
    //...
    public bool Activated{ get; set; }
    public IList<ProjectDetail> ProjectDetails{ get; set; }
}
```

As you can see a project has many details.

```
public class ProjectDetail
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Project Project{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid ProjectId{ get; set; }             
    public string DetailDescription{ get; set; }
    public IList<ProjectDetailsAnswer> ProjectDetailsAnswers{ get; set; }
}
```

And a projectDetail has many answers:

```
public class ProjectDetailsAnswer
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid ProjectDetailId{ get; set; }
    public ProjectDetail ProjectDetail{ get; set; }       
    public string OtherField{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(512)]
    public string AnswerDescription{ get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do is to use Entity Framework with lambda expressions to load a viewmodel

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Guid projectTypeId{ get; set; }
    public string projectType { get; set; }
    public string DetailDescription { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> AnswerDescription{ get; set; }//this propertie comes from ProjectDetailsAnswer.AnswerDescription
}
```

This is my query

```
var result = _dbContext.ProjectDetails //<==search from details
        .Select(x => new ProjectDetailViewModel
        {
            projectTypeId = x.Project.ProjectTypeId,
            projectType = x.Project.projectType,
            DetailDescription = x.DetailDescription,
            AnswerDescription = x.ProjectDetailsAnswers.Select(a => a.AnswerDescription)
        }).ToList();
```

However I realized that I should use a group by because the previous query gives me hundred of records(if project table has 10 records, projectdetail 10, and projectdetailAnswers 10, I will bring 1000 records, because it gives me a list of viewmodel).

So I ended up with this query to group by ProjectTypeId:

```
var result = _dbContext.ProjectDetails //<==search from details
        .Select(x => new ProjectDetailViewModel
        {
            projectTypeId = x.Project.ProjectTypeId,
            projectType = x.Project.projectType,
            DetailDescription = x.DetailDescription,
            AnswerDescription = x.ProjectDetailsAnswers.Select(a => a.AnswerDescription)
        }).GroupBy(x=>x.ProjectTypeId).ToList();
```

however I do not really know what type of data structure it is. Because I would like to pass it to a strongly typed view.

My questions: is my approach to reduce the number of records I load from my database okay?

How do I know what kind of data structure is my result object? (remember I want to pass the result object to a strongly typed view)

Comment: What kind of data structure your view is expecting? Once you define that, you can write code to create that.

Comment: I need a list of ProjectDetailVewModel, but when I query it  inside my result object, I have hundred of records. That is why I tried to use a groupBy. However I do not raelly know what kind of data structure it became

Answer (score 1):

It is better approch to make a query that returns only needed result instead of getting large amount of records and then filter them. I think this code is better choice:

```
var result = _dbContext.ProjectDetails.ProjectDetailsAnswers //<==search from details
        .Select(x => new ProjectDetailViewModel
        {
            projectTypeId = x.ProjectDetail.Project.ProjectTypeId,
            projectType = x.ProjectDetail.Project.projectType,
            DetailDescription = x.ProjectDetail.DetailDescription,
            AnswerDescription = x.Select(a => a.AnswerDescription)
        }).ToList();
```